Failed to resolve: com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
I am unable to download the library in android studio it shows the error I know it's been deprecated but my friend laptop he is able to download the library and build the project
help me fix this it's been 4 months blocking my work
I don't know what the problem is I have check both laptop configuration and is there any android studio blockage system level permissions to be given because that library is located in maven also I am unable to download
